# Correct way to override file permission /dev/null

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions, sudo

I am in a middle of this problem, and not sure which method to follow ?

I am using a **plugin** which writes **temporary files (*.txt / *.tmp etc.)** to `/dev/null`. The plugin is complicated and changing the path is something **`i can't`**.

I am aware of `chown` `chgrp` `chmod` in this context. Also I think that `/dev/null` is restructured after **every reboot**.

Can anyone please guide me so as to change permission to `/dev/null` to execute **plugin** as a **nonsudo** user ??

Comment: A script can't "write" temporary files to /dev/null. (It's likely not a permissions issue: anyone can send data to /dev/null -- it's a bit bucket.) If it's sending data to /dev/null, then that data is obviously irrelevant to the correct working of the script (assuming the script works correctly). If fact, changing /dev/null on your system will likley break not only this script, but also other things on your system. Scripts are just text -- so, yes, you'll have to change the script in order to do what you want.

Comment: thank your for reply ... but I using the word `script` Antonyms for a `plugin`  !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the permissions on `/dev/null` won't help.  [Anything sent there is discarded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device), so there's nothing to read, regardless of your permissions.

If you need the data, don't discard it (by sending it to `dev/null`) in the first place, or copy it before it's discarded.